# Why is the wording of the beracha upon shaking the arba minim only on lulav?

Tags: blessing, words, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

The beracha upon shaking the arba minim is 'על נטילת לולב'? Why is the focus on the lulav specifically rather than a more general blessing like 'על נטילת ארבעה מינים'?

Comment: See Hayim Vital's *Peri Etz Hayim*, Sha'ar HaLulav, Pereq Gimel. I'm not going to pretend to understand it, but I found it by doing a basic search.

Comment: In other words, it can be only understood by understanding the Kabbalah behind the wobbling - the Minim, the directions, etc.

Answer (score 12):

The Gemara ([Sukkah 37B](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Sukkah.pdf)) asks the same question:

> R. Jeremiah enquired of R. Zerika, Why in the blessing do we say only ‘To take the palm-branch’? — Because it towers above the others. Then why should not one lift up the ethrog and recite the blessing over it? — The reason is, the other answered him, that as a species it naturally towers above all of them.

Comment: Still leaves the question of why height is the most important?

Comment: @bondonk https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117617/759