Why don't we make the bracha on the Etrog, instead of the Lulav?
According to the midrash, the Etrog is the species that is the best, because it has a good taste and a good fragrance (which represents Jews who have Mitzvot and Torah, rather than just one or neither).
Why then, is the bracha for the 4 species on the lulav, rather than the etrog? Isn't there a principle that we make a bracha on what is dearest?

The other species are bound together. The esrog stays apart because it knows it's better than the deficient Jews but we bless the lulav because it takes care of the other species. Hashem prefers unity to excellence. Compare to how he punished the idol worshipping but unified first temple Jews for 70 years but is still punishing the divided hateful second temple Jews.

Further details are in the question here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117617/why-is-height-the-determining-factor-for-the-the-blessing-on-the-lulav

I discuss this here: We All Need One Another (Sukkot): https://youtu.be/h4GSx-i3B8o

I give an answer to this question, in this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/145480/31534
